# Selecionar dois elementos no each para pegar horaInicio e Fim de inputs da tela

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, jquery-data

tenho um página em que tenho data inicio e fim, e preciso criar uma validação em que não pode criar nenhum registro caso a hora atual estiver entre essas duas datas.

Tenho a data atual já e estou conseguindo validar com a hora fim, no $('.horaFim').each.

Tem como eu pegar a horaFim e horaInicio no mesmo each? Os dois possuem a classe hora, mas um com a classe "HoraInico" e outra com a "HoraFim".

tks ;>

Estou validando com Javascript da seguinte maneira.

```
var horaAtual=  horas+':'+minutos; // obtenho a data atual

    var Inicio = null; 
    var aponta = true;

    $('.horaFim').each(function (){
        Fim = $(this).val();
        if(Fim > horaAtual){
             $('.horaFim').each(function (){
                Inicio = $(this).val();

                if(Inicio > horaAtual){
                    $('.possuiapontamento').show();
                    aponta = false;
                }

             })
        }            
    })


    if(aponta == true){            
        $.ajax({
                type      : 'post', 
                url       : 'clock.php', 
                dataType  : 'html',
                data: {hora: horaAtual, id: id, statusClock: statusClock},
                success: function( data ){       
                    diaSemana();                         
                }, 
                error: function(xhr) {alert('Erro ao passar variavel: ' + xhr.responseText);}
            });
    }
```

Comment: Se a questão era apenas pegar os 2 no mesmo each, você pode fazer isto: $('.HoraInico', .horaFim).each(/*...*/);
ou
$('.hora').each(/*...*/);

Comment: Sim, mas não estou conseguindo atribuir o valor Inicio na variavel x e horaFim na variavel y, eles estão vindo na mesma.
EX:
Fim = $('.Fim').val();
Inicio = $('.Inicio').val();